ReplayKit : How do I know if user had consented for Screen Capture alert?
I understand that there are no delegate methods for this. But to determine a positive consent from user to Record Screen needs to be evaluated via block parameter.
When user denies the permission by mistake, and, if user tries again, the alert is not showing up. How do I reset the permission and throw the below alert again?


The startCapture(handler:completionHandler:) method of RPScreenRecorder return the error code RPRecordingErrorCode.userDeclined in the completionHandler if the user denies permission.
If you call startCapture(handler:completionHandler:) again after the user has declined, the authorization prompt will appear again.
